# How can I make a fade in function without using jQuery like this? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a simple HTML + CSS + JavaScript (with no jQuery involved) document. If someone tests it he is gonna see that there's a simple text that fades and move when window is loaded.

## Code Explanation :

Well its a very simple piece of code. 
 In html there is a paragraph and with css it's opacity is set to 0. Now with JS this property of opacity is changed every 10 mili seconds by 0.01. But I used some global variables to do it (something I don't want).

## What I want?

I want to make a function like `fadeIn(element, changeOnEveryMiliSecond).` In place of `element` the id of any element I want to fade in and `changeOnEveryMiliSecond` the change in opacity every 10 mili second. Can anyone guide me how I can do it with the code similar like mine and no global variables? Also I don't want to use any library like jQuery. I can do it that way but I am just making my JavaScript concepts better and figuring out how things are done ;) 
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Fade In</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        html{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #main_body{
            background: black;
        }
        #text{
            font: normal 2em ebrima;
            color: white;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var op = 0;
            var pos = 0;
            function main(){
                if(op != 1) op = op + 0.01;
                if(pos != 50) pos = pos + 1;
                document.getElementById('text').style.opacity = op;
                document.getElementById('text').style.top = pos + 'px';
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', setInterval(main, 10), false);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body id="main_body">
        <p id="text">Hello World</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is a solution described here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#fade_in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will 100% work for you, any problem do ask me

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function fadeIn(element, changeOnEveryMiliSecond){
      ChangeInterval = setInterval(
      function(){
        Opacity = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("opacity");
        if(Opacity >= 1){
                   clearInterval(ChangeInterval);
                  }
        element.style.opacity = parseFloat(Opacity) + changeOnEveryMiliSecond;  

      }
      ,10); //set the interval for repeat
    }

        window.addEventListener('load', function(){fadeIn(document.getElementById('text'),0.01);}, false);

    </script>
```

Comment: I need sometime to figure out what is happening!

Comment: take your time, if struck somewhere do seek help

Comment: In js bin  `Line 7: (Opacity >= 1)?clearInterval(ChangeInterval):''; --- Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
Line 11: ,10); //set the interval for repeat --- Comma warnings can be turned off with 'laxcomma'
Line 10: } --- Bad line breaking before ','.`

Comment: it worked form in chrome,opera,safari,ie & ff, unaware of js bin sorry

Comment: which browser your are using, & made some edit for js bin , try the edited code

Comment: Well Thanks! The thing that is new for me is the two window methods but now I figured them out thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the first problem is that you're passing to `addEventListener` the function return instead of the function.

Change

```
window.addEventListener('load', setInterval(main, 10), false);
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){setInterval(main, 10)}, false);
```

Another problem is that you never stop your loop. This works but it's costly. You could either remove the interval with `clearInterval` or use a `setTimeout` based solution.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/xujuv/1/)

Comment: There isn't any problem with my code I'm just asking to make it a function. So that I don't have to make functions like this again and again. And without using global variables

Comment: Yes, there was a problem : you weren't waiting for the page to load. It wouldn't have worked with image.

Comment: The simplest solution to avoid global variables is to use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a (pure) CSS animation:

```
#text{
    top: 0;
    font: normal 2em ebrima;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s forwards; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    moveIn 2s forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      moveIn 2s forwards; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         moveIn 2s forwards; /* IE 10+ */

}
@-webkit-keyframes moveIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; top: 0p; }
  100% { opacity: 1; top: 50px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; top: 0p; }
  100% { opacity: 1; top: 50px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moveIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; top: 0p; }
  100% { opacity: 1; top: 50px; }
}
@keyframes moveIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; top: 0p; }
  100% { opacity: 1; top: 50px; }
}
```

Also check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4x7E6/1/).